# How to keep Android screen on after an action

Tags: android, wakelock, screen-lock

I could have sworn there's a simple line of code for this, but I can't find it right now.

In my app I am using a piece of custom hardware for input. I receive events (on BLE) but not as keypresses or mouse actions. What I want to do is that each action should keep the screen awake just as if I had touched the screen (so, whatever the current timeout is gets reset)

To be clear - I do NOT want to use

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

since that leaves the screen permanently on. I also don't want to be running a bunch of wakelocks - I'm almost certain there is a simple command to reset the screen timeout - what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use Wakelock, some options:

- Use [SnackBar](https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/showing) to briefly display a pop-up message.
- Use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) to fire a high priority message notification.
- Create a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) that runs while your BLE device is allowing user input. Or use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) the same way.

A more severe option, which requires your app to be a [device admin](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin), is to use [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setMaximumTimeToLock(android.content.ComponentName,%20long)) to set the maximum time to lock, ideally saving previous value and restoring after user input is complete.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to accept this because its a good, complete answer. In the end, I'm going to actually do what I swore I would not and use the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON with a timer (shoot me now)